# How to pass a listview.builder in flutter_slidable (Slidable)

Tags: flutter

This is just a simple todo list app. I want to implement a feature which lets me mark a task as complete when swiping right and delete the task when swiping left. This app uses a database and stores an added task in a list of type database (`List<TodoItem> Itemlist= <TodoItem>[];`).

Is it possible to use flutter_slidable?.

I have tried using `Dismissible` but i could only get it to delete the task.

```
  List<TodoItem> Itemlist= <TodoItem>[];

     SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: Itemlist.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                            String item = Itemlist[index].toString();
                          return Dismissible(
                              key: Key(UniqueKey().toString()),
                              onDismissed: (direction){
                                setState((){
                                    deleteItem(Itemlist[index].id, index);
                                }
                                );
                              },

                              background: Container(
                                child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                color: Colors.red,
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                              ),
                              child: Itemlist[index],
                          );
                          }
                      ),
                    )
```

I want to get the same result as below but am unsure on how to pass the `listview.builder` in `Slidable`.

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap your tile widget with Slidable
2. Setup "actionPane" and "actions" parameters for Slidable